# Scroll Two List view simultenious in View Pager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

i have two list view in View Pager, i want to scroll two list simultaneous.
but only one visible at a time.
how can i do this?

design is

```
     View Pager
    -------------
    |          |           |
    |          |           |
    |          |           |
    |LISTVIEW 1| lISTVIEW 2|
    |          |           |
    |          |           |
    |          |           |
    <-visible area-->
   --------------
```

Comment: i have take view pager and set adapter(contains two listview) .

Answer (score 0):

Call this when you switch between `ListView`'s :

When going from list 1 to list 2:

```
   mListView2.setSelection(mListView1.getfirstVisiblePosition());
```

When going from list 2 to list 1:

```
   mListView1.setSelection(mListView2.getfirstVisiblePosition());
```

Listen to `ViewPager` with [`OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) , use [`onPageSelected(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html#onPageSelected%28int%29)

Comment: but where to write this code. any idea..   is there any event when i scroll viewpager from list 1 to 2 or vice versa.

Comment: instead of listening to view pager, can we listen to list view itself?